# Not sending the right page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am creating a website and to do so, the Admin Account has access to create posts. While doing this, I have come across the error of when running the postLaunchCourse function sends me to 403 (No access) page and wont post it.

The code:

```js
exports.getLaunchCourse = (req, res) => {
  res.render("admin/launch-course", {
    isAdmin: req.user && req.user.role === "admin" ? true : false,
    isAutherized: req.user ? true : false,
    username: req.user ? req.user.username : null,
  });
};

// Type : POST
// Access : Private (Only For Admin)
// @Desc : Upload Course To Server
exports.postLaunchCourse = (req, res, next) => {
  const title = req.body.title;
  const description = req.body.description;
  const price = req.body.price;
  const thumbnail = req.file ? req.file.path : null;
  const facultyAccess = req.body.facultyAccess.split(",");
  const tags = req.body.tags.split(",");

  cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(thumbnail, (error, result) => {
    deleteFileHandler.deleteFileHandler(thumbnail);
    const course = new Course({
      creator: req.user,
      title: title,
      description: description,
      price: price,
      thumbnail: result.url,
      tags: tags,
      facultyAccess: facultyAccess,
    });

    course
      .save()
      .then((course) => {
        console.log("Course Created Successfully");
        res.redirect("/course/" + course._id);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        const error = new Error("Wasn't able to Create-Course");

        next(error);
      });
  });
};
```

I've tried changing the code and looking at other fixes but it wont work. I am expecting the post function to run properly and for it to post onto Remote Courses section.